# database is updating temporarily(i know it because i saw db using adb pull method)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to update my database values. I tried updating my sqlite database using this code. my database is updating temporarily(i saw the database using adb pull).
On killing the activity all values are set to zero...

This is the Dialogue for input. lead.setPositive_result() increment the value by 1, so does lead.setZero_result().

```
                            boolean status = sales_status.isChecked();
                                if (sales_status.isChecked()) {
                                    long oldsales;
                                    long old_pos;
                                    total_sales = Long.parseLong(userInput.getText().toString());
                                    oldsales=lead.getTotal_sales();
                                    total_sales=total_sales+oldsales;
                                    lead.setTotal_sales(total_sales);
                                    lead.setPostive_result();
                                    customerdatasource.updatesales(lead, status);
                                    Log.i("Positive","************ positive result is being processed");
                                } else
                                {    Log.i("Negative","************ negative result is being processed");
                                    lead.setZero_result();
                                    customerdatasource.updatesales(lead,status);
                                }
                                    Toast.makeText(lead_list.this, "Lead Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this part of code is dedicated for updating my database.

```
public void updatesales(Lead lead, boolean status)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = leaddbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    if(status==true)
        contentValues.put(dbschema.Leadentry.Column_positive_result,lead.getPostive_result());

    else
        contentValues.put(dbschema.Leadentry.Column_zero_result,lead.getZero_result());

    contentValues.put(dbschema.Leadentry.Column_total_sales,lead.getTotal_sales());
    int res=db.update(dbschema.Leadentry.Table_name, contentValues, "_ID = ?" , new String[] {String.valueOf(lead.getId())});
    db.close();
}
```

I am a noobie to android development. please be kind.

Comment: so, when you restart your application, the db resets?

Comment: no, only these three values i.e. Total_sales, Pos_result and Zero_result got reset. i have other 7 values too.. they remain unchanged.

Comment: ok, i suggest using database debugger like stetho, also debug your code where you update the values to check when it gets called.